# JMeter bugs when trying to stress test localhost server

Tags: java, jmeter, benchmarking

I am trying to do a stress test to a localhost server. i have configured the HTTP Request Defaults correctly, image attached. The View Results tree panel shows that JMeter is trying to send the request to ${host}. I am using v 3, the current latest release. Please help.

[image]
[image]

Comment: just add ip address or 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost and it will work.

Answer (score 1):

[HTTP Request Defaults](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request_Defaults) are really **defaults**.

- If you leave `Server Name or IP` input for you "Home Page" request blank - the value will be picked up from the HTTP Request Defaults
- If you override `Server Name of IP` with something else - in your case with `${host}` - default value will be discarded.

So all you need to do is go to your "Home Page" HTTP Request Sampler and delete `${host}` from the `Server Name or IP` input.

Detailed information: [Why It's SO Important To Use JMeter's HTTP Request Defaults](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/why-its-so-important-use-jmeters-http-request-defaults)

Comment: thanks, i think this is it. but then, why does JMeter completely ignore the path? Per my config, i expect a request to http://localhost:7474/ext/service/helloworld, but the request is sent out to http://localhost:7474/ . Any ideas why?

Comment: The same situation. If you leave the `Path` blank - the value from the HTTP Request Defaults will be used. If you have anything else in the `Path` - the value will be overriden

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing "${host} " with actual hostname.

If you are using ${host} then you have to provide the values to it using CSV Config File or some other means.

Go through the link http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config